# CakePHP Login with both username and email using Auth Component

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-1.3

I want the auth component to allow user to login entrying either username or email.
In my users table, both fields - userName and userEmail  are unique.
At time of registration, the password is generated like:

sha1($username.$password);

The problem is that user is not able to login using email.

**App Controller**

```
 var $components = array('Auth');

 public function beforeFilter(){

if(isset($this->params['prefix']) && $this->params['prefix'] == 'webadmin') {

       $this->Auth->userModel = 'Admin';
      $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = $this->Auth->loginAction = array('prefix' => 'webadmin', 'controller' => 'login', 'action' => 'index');
        $this->Auth->loginError = 'Invalid Username/Password Combination!';
        $this->Auth->authError = 'Please login to proceed further!';
         $this->Auth->flashElement = "auth.front.message";
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('prefix'=>'webadmin', 'controller'=>'dashboard', 'action'=>'index');
            }
          else{


         $this->layout="front";  

        //$this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;

        // $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    //   $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'=>'blogs', 'action'=>'index');
         $this->Auth->fields = array(
            'username' => 'userName',
            'password' => 'password'
           );
          $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.status'=>1); 

         $this->Auth->loginError = "The username/email and password you entered doesn't match our records.";
         $this->Auth->authError = 'Please login to view this page!';
         $this->Auth->flashElement = "auth.front.message";
         $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'=>'profiles', 'action'=>'index');

    }
```

**Users Controller**: the login function goes like:

```
if(!empty($this->data))
{ 
   // Try to login with Email
    if (!empty($this->Auth->data)) {
    // save username entered in the login form
    $username = $this->Auth->data['User']['userName'];

    // find a user by e-mail
    $find_by_email = $this->User->find('first', array(
                    'conditions' => array('userEmail' => $this->Auth->data['User']['userName']),
                    'fields' => 'userName'));
        // found
        if (!empty($find_by_email))
        {

        $this->Auth->data['User']['userName'] = $find_by_email['User']['userName'];
        $this->data['User']['password']=$this->Auth->data['User']['password'];

          if (!$this->Auth->login($this->data)) {

            // login failed
            // bring back the username entered in the login form
            $this->Auth->data['User']['username'] = $username;
          } else {
          $this->Session->delete('Message.auth');
          // redirect
          if ($this->Auth->autoRedirect) {
          $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(), null, true);
          }
        }
       }
    }
}
```

**Auth.php:(I have made some changes here in the way password is generated as I am using the cakephp session to auto-login to SMF forum.)**

```
    function login($data = null) {
 $data['User.password'] = sha1(strtolower($data['User.userName']) . $_POST['data']['User']['password']);


        $this->__setDefaults();
        $this->_loggedIn = false;

        if (empty($data)) {
            $data = $this->data;
        }

        if ($user = $this->identify($data)) {

            $this->Session->write($this->sessionKey, $user);
            $this->_loggedIn = true;
        }
        return $this->_loggedIn;
    }
```

I took help from [this](http://www.netboy.pl/2011/08/cakephp-auth-component-login-with-username-or-e-mail/) link, but I am not getting username in $data['User.userName'] in auth.php, I getting email here, so the password goes wrong and results in login failure.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could make it work is by modifying auth.php in cake.

**App Controller**
I added this to the code in before filter:

```
 $this->Auth->fields = array(
        'username' => 'userName',
    'email'=>'userEmail',
        'password' => 'password'
     );
```

**Users Controller** I removed all the extra code.

**Auth.php**
I made changes to the identify function to check email after encrypting the password in //the way I wanted.

```
function identify($user = null, $conditions = null) {
        if ($conditions === false) {
            $conditions = array();
        } elseif (is_array($conditions)) {
            $conditions = array_merge((array)$this->userScope, $conditions);
        } else {
            $conditions = $this->userScope;
        }
        $model =& $this->getModel();


        if (empty($user)) {
            $user = $this->user();
            if (empty($user)) {
                return null;
            }
        } elseif (is_object($user) && is_a($user, 'Model')) {
            if (!$user->exists()) {
                return null;
            }
            $user = $user->read();
            $user = $user[$model->alias];
        } elseif (is_array($user) && isset($user[$model->alias])) {
            $user = $user[$model->alias];
        }

        if (is_array($user) && (isset($user[$this->fields['username']]) || isset($user[$model->alias . '.' . $this->fields['username']]))) {
            if (isset($user[$this->fields['username']]) && !empty($user[$this->fields['username']])  && !empty($user[$this->fields['password']])) {
                if (trim($user[$this->fields['username']]) == '=' || trim($user[$this->fields['password']]) == '=') {
                    return false;
                }
                $find = array(
                    $model->alias.'.'.$this->fields['username'] => $user[$this->fields['username']],
                    $model->alias.'.'.$this->fields['password'] => $user[$this->fields['password']]
                );
            } elseif (isset($user[$model->alias . '.' . $this->fields['username']]) && !empty($user[$model->alias . '.' . $this->fields['username']])) {
                if (trim($user[$model->alias . '.' . $this->fields['username']]) == '=' || trim($user[$model->alias . '.' . $this->fields['password']]) == '=') {
                    return false;
                }

            // my code starts
            $user['User.userEmail']=$user['User.userName']; 
    //find username using email
        $find_by_email= $model->find('first', array(
                'fields' => array('User.userName','User.realpass'), 
                'conditions' => array($model->alias.'.'.$this->fields['email'] => $user[$model->alias . '.' . $this->fields['email']]),
                'recursive' => 0
            )); 



        if(!empty($find_by_email))
        {
        $uname=strtolower($find_by_email['User']['userName']);
        $pwd=$user[$model->alias . '.' . $this->fields['password']];
        }
        else
        {
        $uname=strtolower($user[$model->alias . '.' . $this->fields['username']]);
        $pwd=$user[$model->alias . '.' . $this->fields['password']];
        }
         $thepassword = sha1($uname.$pwd); // encrypt password


            // find user where username or email equals to the username passed  
                $find = array(
                    'OR' => array($model->alias.'.'.$this->fields['username'] => $user[$model->alias . '.' . $this->fields['username']], $model->alias.'.'.$this->fields['email'] => $user[$model->alias . '.' . $this->fields['username']]),
                    $model->alias.'.'.$this->fields['password'] => $thepassword
                );
            } else {
                return false;
            }


            $cond=array_merge($find, $conditions);

            $data = $model->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => $cond,
                'recursive' => 0
            ));

  // my code ends here

            if (empty($data) || empty($data[$model->alias])) {
                return null;
            }
        } elseif (!empty($user) && is_string($user)) {
            $data = $model->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array_merge(array($model->escapeField() => $user), $conditions),
            ));
            if (empty($data) || empty($data[$model->alias])) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        if (!empty($data)) {
            if (!empty($data[$model->alias][$this->fields['password']])) {
                unset($data[$model->alias][$this->fields['password']]);
            }
            return $data[$model->alias];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Lastly, I commented the password encrypt code to return the simple password so that I can encrypt it the wat I needed in the above function.

```
function password($password) {
//return Security::hash($password, null, true);
 return $password;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have error in the conditions, it should be:

```
'conditions' => array('userEmail' => $this->Auth->data['User']['email']),
```

You are checking the username .

Comment: this is not an error. I am getting email in the field called userName