# Cake Php Auth Email or Username login

Tags: php, cakephp

I currently have the below set up for use with the Auth component, its working perfectly however my client would now like to be give the users the option to sign in with a username or email address.

My current set up:

```
AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.Customer';

        $this->Auth->allow();

        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'Customer',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password',
                ),
                'scope' => array(
                    'Customer.guest' => 0,
                ),
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish',
            )
        );

        $this->Auth->loginAction = array(
            'controller' => 'customers',
            'action' => 'login',
            'admin' => false,
            'plugin' => false,
        );
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
            'controller' => 'customers',
            'action' => 'my_account',
            'admin' => false,
            'plugin' => false,
        );

        if($this->Auth->user('id') == false){
            $this->Auth->authError = 'Please login to continue';
        }

        $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');
```

How would I be able to change this so that the log requires either 'email' or a new field 'username'.

I would assume a OR statement however the below does not work:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'Customer',
                'fields' => array(

                    'password' => 'password',
                    'OR' => array(
                                'username' => 'email',
                                'username' => 'username'
                    )
                ),
                'scope' => array(
                    'Customer.guest' => 0,
                ),
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish',
            )
        );
```

Comment: http://findnerd.com/list/view/Using-Email-or-Username-to-login-with-auth-in-cakephp/929/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392322/cakephp-login-with-both-username-and-email-using-auth-component

Answer (score 0):

I have tried by changing configure but not able to do. I have customize my login identify code like as below:

```
 $findByEmail = $this->Users->findByEmail($this->request->data['username'])->first();
if (isset($findByEmail->username) && $findByEmail->username) {
  $this->request->data['username'] = $findByEmail->username;
 }
  $user = $this->Auth->identify();
```

---

And this work for both value whatever username or email